# SVN branching Selective merging without feature flag

Tags: svn, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I want to start using SVN for my team, One main trunk and weekly Release branch for test and go live was what i was thinking. However, There are projects which doesn't want to go live until unspecific period. Lets say Jan 1, team start making changes in components A, B, C and D. However, by Mar 1, Component C and D is included in Projects that won't go live until August 1. 
How can I ignore Changes made in Components C and D being included in Release branches in between Mar 1 to Aug 1? Especially because "Feature Flag" cannot be applied to these code as it is not custom code, rather oracle code off the shelf?
I also thought of Trunk, QA Branch and Release branch each week. Team would make changes in Trunk, they check in on Dev branch, Whenever they are done, they promote/merge to QA branch. After testing in QA branch, it will be Release by weekly Prod release branch. However, I am told, there is no way to exclude Component C and D, as Selective merge in SVN. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Branch per Task - if "Changes made in Components C and D" are separate branches, you'll not merge it into release-branch (or trunk before branching Release), until it isn't needed (but *can* update task-branches from mainline)

Comment: Thks Lazy B, to add clarity,Dev team works in Trunk. All components ABCD is changed in Trunk.
1)Wkly release branch: 
Issue:Comps with Work-in-progress changes will also have to go live on Weekly Rel branch.Feature-flag wont work to supress those changes
2)Dev makes change in Dev Branch,components with work-in-progress changes continues to be worked on in Dev branch,wont be merged to Trunk,hence, only changes planned for upcoming release will be merged from Dev to Trunk,and,Wkly rel branch from trunk.
Issue: Im told,cant selectively merge just comps A, B from Dev to Trunk. 
Can anyone help?